# How to extract value between 2 slashes

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a string like "`1490/2334/5166400411000434`" from which I need to derive value after second slash. I tried below logic

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('1490/2334/5166400411000434','[^/]+',1,3) from dual;
```

it is working fine. But when i dont have value between first and second slash it is returining blank.
For example my string is "1490//5166400411000434" and am trying

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('1490//5166400411000434','[^/]+',1,3) from dual;
```

it is returning blank.
 Please suggest me what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you may need

```
regexp_substr(t, '(([^/]*/){2})([^/]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 3)
```

This handles the first 2 parts like `'xxx/'` and then checks for a sequence of non `/` characters; the parameter `3` is used to get the 3rd matching subexpression, which is what you want.
For example:

```
with test(t) as (
    select '1490/2334/5166400411000434' from dual union all
    select '1490//5166400411000434' from dual union all
    select '1490//5166400411000434/ramesh/3344' from dual
)
select t, regexp_substr(t, '(([^/]*/){2})([^/]*)', 1, 1, 'i', 3) as substr
from test
```

gives:

```
T                                  SUBSTR                            
---------------------------------- ----------------------------------
1490/2334/5166400411000434         5166400411000434                  
1490//5166400411000434             5166400411000434                  
1490//5166400411000434/ramesh/3344 5166400411000434
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `REVERSE()` your string and take the value before the first slash. And then reverse again to obtain the desired output.

```
select reverse(regexp_substr(reverse('1490//5166400411000434'), '[^/]+', 1, 1)) from dual;
```

It can also be done with basic substring and instr function:

```
select reverse(SUBSTR(reverse('1490//5166400411000434'), 0, INSTR(reverse('1490//5166400411000434'), '/')-1)) from dual;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually i want to get the value between 2nd and 3rd slash i.e 5166400411000434. My input string may contain many slashes like '1490//5166400411000434/ramesh/3344'.

Answer (score 0):

Use other options in REGEXP_SUBSTR to match a pattren

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR('1490//5166400411000434','(/\d*)/(\d+)',1,1,'x',2) from dual
```

Basically it is finding the pattren of two / including digits starting from 1 with 1 appearance and ignoring whitespaces ('x') then outputting 2nd subexpression that is in second expression within ()
... pattern,1,1,'x',subexp2)